# django: aggregating log entries by certain fixed time period

Tags: django, aggregate

I have a log table in my database which holds all user actions. In this table there is a column called 'money' which indicates how much money this user had on that day (there is also a 'timestamp' column for each log entry)

How can I retrieve data from that table grouped by week or month, aggregated with average value for money?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to precalculate the week and/or month and store that data into another field.  Then the query is as easy as `YourTable.objects.values('week', 'year').annotate(Avg('money))`.

You *should* also be able to do this with extra() parameters, but that is sometimes tricky.  That would look like

```
YourTable.objects.extra(select={
     'week': 'some_method_to_calculate_week_from_timestamp(timestamp)'
}).values('week').annotate(Avg('money'))
```

How you would calculate the week from timestamp in this second case would depend on your DB.  If postgres the information you need would be in here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html